# Arduino reset with FTDI breakout question

Tags: arduino, ftdi, reset

How do you get the [SparkFun FTDI Basic Breakout](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9115) board to auto reset?

I still have to hit the reset button for any Arduino clones when I use the breakout board. I have tried connecting to the DTR pin and other methods of trial and error but I am just not getting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did to get my breadboard arduino to reset was to go into the device manager (Windows 7) and highlighted the FTDI device (A virtual COM port) and then went to Properties, Port settings, Advanced. I then checked off the box that said "Set Rts on close". After I did this my arduino reset itself no problem.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm on XP but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I use the Sparkfun FTDI 5V basic board with my Arduino Mini Pro 328 boards and I have no problems with auto reset, I plug it in and upload using the Ardunio IDE (I use 017) - it works fine. Is this an issue with your clone Arduino boards? You do not say which clones you have.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the FTDI 3.3V breakout from sparkfun, the 5V cable from FTDI and the 3.3v cable from sparkfun with an RBBB arduino clone.  they all reset the board without problem.  the auto-reset is a feature of the arduino bootloader as i understand.  perhaps your cloan has a different bootloader

Perhaps you could mention which arduino clone you are using and maybe someone has some specific experience with this issue on it, or we can checkout what the bootloader supports

Comment: Auto reset is a feature of the electronics of the board itself, not the bootloader.